# A problem regarding integration by definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

The textbook I picked this problem from is R. Courant’s “Differential and Integral Calculus; Vol. 1”. It is located in the problem set of Chapter 2, subchapter 2 — problem 5.(a):

*Using the methods in text (i.e. by considering partial sums), evaluate the integral $$ \int_{a}^{b} (x+1)^{\alpha} dx,$$ where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary integer.*

I shall first note that the examples of integration provided in the textbook precisely before the problem set (implicating that the “text” part of the problem essenstially means “in the manner which is alike to that of those examples”), have omitted the case of $\alpha = -1$ (which is, to some extent, obvious, for the answer to this problem, which can be found at the end of the textbook, is but a formula which loses meaning if $\alpha = -1$; naturally, a natural logarithm, which has not been introduced in the book so far, would emerge in this case). So in fact I shall only regard the case $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1\}$. That I do understand, but that already implies that the formulation of the problem lacks clarity ($\alpha$ is not just an arbitrary integer).

The cumbersome part, however, does not lie here. When in the examples the author was solving a virtually identical problem of integrating $$\int_{a}^{b} x^{\alpha} dx,$$ where $\alpha$ is, once again, an arbitrary integer other than -1, he introduced a seemingly arbitrary (though necessary for the demonstration he made to obtain valid) condition of $0 < a < b$. The bit I cannot understand is whether I should introduce similar conditions (in my case, these shall be $-1 < a < b$) or not, considering that in the latter case I would be forced to consider numerous variants of respective locations of $a$ and $b$ on the number line, also taking into account that $a,b \neq -1$ if $\alpha < 0$. Another problem emerges when we let $\alpha = 0$, for that would implicate the expression of $0^0$ if either $a$ or $b$ are equal to -1; the expression on the matter of which, as far as I am concerned, no consensus has yet been reached among textbook authors.

**The question:** Considering everything I have said earlier, should I, just like the author, introduce the conditions of $-1 < a < b$, which would make the problem a lot easier and the approach to it — natural, or should I solely regard the case of greatest generality, but of painstaking complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter, i.e. are you graded for this? If not, why not try both ways? I don't think your condition of $-1<a<b$ is particularly natural so I wouldn't go down that road. One thing you could try though is considering the binomial theorem applied to $(x+1)^\alpha$, since $\alpha$ is an integer. At the end of the day, I don't think anyone of us here can tell you what Richard Courant was thinking when he wrote that.

Comment: The problem is (1) the binomial theorem cannot be applied here, for $\alpha$ can be negative as well, (2) the condition I mentioned stems naturally from interpreting the problem geometrically (i.e. on a graph).

Comment: Oh, and I have also mentioned that I have to approach this problem as the author did, i.e. by considering partial sums.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see where you mentioned in your post that you're using partial sums, did I miss it? If not, you might want to modify your post accordingly because this is important information. Also, the binomial theorem can be used with negative exponents, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations
As I said, this is not really something that people can help you with I think because you're asking a question of interpretation, we can only guess what's expected of you.